# remove blank cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview

Right now i am working with UICollection view, which i am trying to make a grid view! for loading images

[image]

i have a array with Title, which i am displaying on toolbar by using index.section.

now my problem is. if the count of section is odd number there with be an empty space in between the sections something like this.[image]

for avoiding this i am loading all images in one section, but now as i have one section i cannot updates my title from the title array. i am running out of idea's to handle both .

do anyone have some solution or idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one solution to your problem:

1. Create an NSMutableArray and have it contain all of your array
   for different sections.
2. Keep using sections, but create an if
       condition to check if the array count is odd. In this case, you can
       stretch your last cell to fit the whole width. (I used this in one
       of my apps).

Comment: i don't want to stretch it instead can i move it to next section??

Comment: You can't move it to the next section, since each section has to be separated from the section below it. Why don't you like the mutable array idea?

Comment: sorry, i did not understand NSMutableArray logic can you please elaborate

Comment: I understand that you're using an array for each category. So I was suggesting to have all your data in 1 array instead.

Comment: @DaniA i m using mutable array and could u tell how to remove empty cell from collection view